# Can I say "as first as possible"

Tags: british-english

I have a probably a very simple question. In program code one function has to be executed as one of the first ones. Can I say ***"as first as possible"*** (some other functions have to be executed before this function). Generally I want to emphasis that this function has to be executed not as first one (as it depends on other ones) but as early as it possible.

Sorry for my bad English but it is not my first language.

Comment: You use the phrase ‘as early as possible’ yourself (‘as soon as possible’ would probably be more common here, but both are fine). From that sentence you can see that the construction _as X as…_ takes a regular, positive form of the adjective. _First_ is a superlative form (it doesn’t have a positive or comparative). Does that tell you the answer?

Comment: I would say that "first" is the *positive* form that does not have a comparative or a superlative. But other than that, yeah, what Janus says.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes I use the phrase "as early as possible". My intention was to make it stronger. But yes thank you very much for the clarification

Comment: @P__J__ Well, you could say "As close to first as possible".

Comment: Generally you can also say "as soon as possible," but in this context as "one of the first" you might want to be specific in saying *which* functions is must be called ahead of. If you call it an *initialisation* function then programmers will probably understand.

Comment: @WeatherVane it is part of the initialisation sequence - which may vary. But because it initializes one of the memory subsystems it has to be called as soon as all other absolutely necessary initialisation functions were called.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Apart from being morphologically (and historically) formed as a superlative, with the _-st_ suffix, _first_ also behaves like a superlative syntactically in most ways: its use with the indefinite article is similarly restricted (‘he’s an early/\*first riser’ vs ‘he’s the earliest/first riser’), it can be intensified with modifiers like _absolute_ (‘at the absolute earliest/first hour’ vs ‘at the absolute *early hour’), it can be used partitively (‘best/worst/first of all’ vs ‘\*good/\*bad of all’), etc. Historically, it has a comparative (_fore_), too, but not really anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I think I would understand the meaning if someone used that phrase (depending on the context), however I can tell you as a native English speaker, I have never heard anyone say that. I would suggest saying "as early as possible" instead, as you mentioned in your own question.

The primary definition of the word "first" (as given in New Oxford American Dictionary) is: "Coming before all others in time or order; earliest; 1st." So I don't think it would be correct by definition to say "as first as possible", however understandable it may be.

Comment: But it is in common use: one of the first, among the first etc. which logically does not have any sense (you can be the first or not). That led me to the conclusion that *first* can be also used in *as first as ....*

Comment: @P__J__ ‘One of the first’ and its ilk do make sense. That’s a hidden plural, and it refers to the _group_ of things/people that make up the first group. You can talk about the first 500 people with no logical flaw, dividing all the people into groups of 500 and specifying the first of these groups. The reason you can’t say ‘as first as possible’ isn’t that there’s a logical flaw, but a grammatical one. Logically it makes perfect sense, but syntactically, the construction requires a different form (the positive), which doesn’t exist for _first_.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly say *as first as possible*.  Not formally, perhaps, since *first* would be sufficient, but in a talk it might fall in nicely with expressions like *as large as possible* and *as small as possible*.

It resonates with a more famous expression about military strategy: *Get there firstest with the mostest.*  The unusual and ungrammatical usage of *first* and *most* is what makes the saying memorable.

However, *Get there firstest with the mostest* is usually attributed to General Nathan Bedford Forrest, who fought on the Confederate side in the U.S. Civil War, and was an early supporter of the Klu Klux Klan. His biography and other quotations are on Wikiquote (link below). It’s a long reach, but anything that brings a quotation to mind will also tend to draw in everything else about the person being quoted, and in Forrest’s case it would help to know something about him in advance.

https://en.m.wikiquote.org/wiki/Nathan_Bedford_Forrest